# Как правильно работать с базой данных из нескольких окон?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Как организовать работу с одной базой данных `SQLite` из нескольких окон?

Я пишу программу, которая позволяет в БД вносить подключаемые к компьютеру съемные устройства и вести историю подключений.

С помощью `Entity Framework` и пакетов `SQLite`, я создал класс `Context`, который совпадает с таблицами в БД (реализует `DbSet` и т.д.) и сделал класс `DbManager`, который позволяет ввести более высокоуровневые абстракции типа добавить устройство и т.д.

Применительно к `MVVM` этот код является моделью, и я его разместил в соответствующем месте, но не знаю как быть далее.
У меня есть несколько окон, одни позволяют вносить записи, другие позволяют просматривать, редактировать и т.д., соответственно в каждом окне надо создать экземпляр класса `DbManager`? Это вроде как ресурсоемкая операция, и логичнее было бы использовать один экземпляр этого класса во всех окнах.

В общем как сделать работу с базой данных из нескольких окон правильно и соблюдая паттерн `MVVM`?

Comment: *в каждом окне надо создать экземпляр класса DbManager? Это вроде как ресурсоемкая операция* — почему вы так считаете?

Comment: Ресурсоемким является создание подключение к базе данных, а не само создание экземпляра `DbContext`. В данном случае `Entity Framework` берет эту задачу на себя, управляя пулом подключений у себя внутри. Поэтому проще и лучше создать новый экземпляр Context и использовать его в пределах одного ViewModel.

Comment: Ну и да, один экземпляр, размазанный по приложению, может создавать проблемы в дальнейшем. У меня было такое при переписывании однопоточного кода на многопоточный, хотя суть проблемы уже не помню.

Comment: Using (var db = new dbmanager){что  - то делать}

Comment: @АндрейNOP, когда я создаю экземпляр DbContext и делаю загрузку базы - db.Table1.Load() под отладчиком это проходит долго, вот я и засомневался в том, как это сделать

Comment: а зачем вы делаете эту загрузку?

Comment: у меня есть [pet проект](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient), настольное приложение, только я использую EF Compact, но суть та же. Я создаю репозитории как сингтоны, но внутри репозитория я создаю контекст для каждого действия с базой. Возможно вам будет интересно глянуть.

Comment: @tym32167 что бы связать данные с формой и отобразить их на ней